# GLIBCXX versions

Tags: c++, linux, portability, glibc

If I compile a C++ program on my machine, and run it on another one (with older software) I get: `` /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found ``.

In fact on my system glibc is newer (I got gcc-libs 4.5.1: libstdc++.so.6.0.14) and `strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` prints from `GLIBCXX_3.4` to `GLIBCXX_3.4.14`. On the other system, instead, it only prints up to `GLIBCXX_3.4.8` (I got libstdc++.so.6.0.8).

So I've got a few questions:

1. Why my linker links C++ binaries against libstdc++ version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9` instead of `GLIBCXX_3.4.14`?
2. If I complied my binary against libstdc++ version `GLIBCXX_3.4` I guess it would run almost on everywhere. Would that imply any sort of issues? (eg: would it use older -and thus worse- algorithm implementations?)
3. If instead I **statically** link my program against my libstdc++ I guess it will run everywhere; the binary will be a lot bigger (~1MB) of course, any other pros/cons?
4. Can I force the linker to link my binary against a given version of libstdc++?

Comment: You should be using `objdump` to inspect the library, not `strings`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `readelf -a` and `objdump -x` to inspect ELF files in preference to `strings`.

Actually, all the GLIBCXX_* versions don't apply to the entire library, but to each symbol (symbol versioning, see [DSO-howto](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)). So you can have e.g: `std::char_traits<wchar_t>::eq@@GLIBCXX_3.4.5` and `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()@@GLIBCXX_3.4` on the same library file.

The fact that your program needs GLIBCXX_3.4.9 probably means that it has been linked against a symbol that has been introduced/has changed semantics on GLIBCXX_3.4.9.

Comment: Also c++filt can be helpful if yo uhave C++ code.  For example:

readelf -aW <file> | c++filt

Answer (score 1):

1. That the the library version that is installed on your system. You could
   manually build the glibc version 3.4.14 and link to it
2. That depends. Maybe the later version fixed some issues. The users of your program would have to link against the version that your program requires
3. The memory usage is higher
4. Yes, pass proper parameter to the linker. If you need specific version of the library, then it is best to download it, and build it manually, and link to it.

**EDIT**

I just remembered that statically linked libraries increase the memory usage.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams So, I got 2 out of 4. For 1), I guess it is missing dependencies for the glibc. If 3 is not correct, I guess I live in ignorance. So, how to correct those two?

Comment: 1 I'm not certain of, but the library does have `GLIBCXX_3.4.14` *in it*, it's just not using it for some reason. For 3, consider the implications of not being able to update the library.

Comment: If you statically link the library, then you do not care to update it. All symbols are there. Updating the application is worse, because it is going to be larger

Comment: 1. I've got only libstdc++.so.6.0.14 installed. Besides ninjalj's answer is giving a different explaination... 4. What would be the proper parameter?

Comment: Same as linking other static libraries - pass it as a parameter when linking. http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, if your binaries don't use the new features of newer GLIBCXX version, then they won't be linked with that version. So your binaries was linked with GLBCXX 3.4.9, there must be at least one symbol exported from it, and there're no any symbols exported from version newer than 3.4.9.